# Odata Navigation property causing 404 error

Tags: c#, odata

I have been looking around for an answer to this question, but I don't think anyone on SO has faced this exact problem. Really briefly, I am using the reflection provider in C# to create an odata service ([like so](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728281%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)), and will have two entities: Blocks and Roots.

Blocks are much like files and directories in a filesystem, some can have children blocks and some cannot. Roots are like different user accounts, and a device can only belong to one Root. Here's what I have so far:

Classes.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization; 
using System.Data.Services.Common;
using System.Data.Services;

[DataServiceEntity]
public class Block
{
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public int ID { set; get; }
    public int PID { set; get; }
}

public class ParentBlock : Block
{
    public List<Block> Children { set; get; }

    public int Count { get { return Children.Count(); } }

    public ParentBlock()
    {
        Children = new List<Block>();
    }
}

/*other classes that inherit from Block or ParentBlock*/

[DataServiceEntity]
[DataServiceKey("User")]
public class Root
{
    public string User { set; get; }
    public int ID { set; get; }

    public List<Block> Children { set; get; }

    public Root()
    {
        Children = new List<Block>();
    }
}
```

Main.cs

```
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
public class RootDataService : DataService<RootService>
{
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
        config.UseVerboseErrors = true;
        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = System.Data.Services.Common.DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
    }
}

public class RootService
{
    private List<Root> RootList = new List<Root>();
    private List<Block> BlockList = new List<Block>();

    public RootService()
    {
        /*initializes RootList and BlockList with test data*/
    }

    public IQueryable<Root> Roots
    {
        get
        {
            return RootList.AsQueryable<Root>();
        }
    }

    public IQueryable<Block> Blocks
    {
        get
        {
           return BlockList.AsQueryable<Block>();
        }
    }
}
```

This all works pretty well. I run the program, navigate to my browser and I get two collections, Roots and blocks. I can do odata/Roots to get both test accounts, odata/Roots('account1') to get the first account's User and ID. I can do odata/Roots('account1')/Children(5) and get the Block with ID of 5.

But... when I try to do odata/Roots('account1')/Children(5)/Children or odata/Block(5)/Children, I get a 404. This is frustrating since I added validation code to my `RootService` constructor and the Count property shows that Block(5) has children (2 of them), but I cannot navigate to them? I'm certain there's something pretty obvious that I'm missing, but I haven't found it. More baffling is that both `Root` and `ParentBlock` have identical code in regards to making their `Children` list available to outside classes, but only one of them is navigable. I am grateful for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model, the `Block` type does not have a property called `Children`.  Did you mean to refer to `ParentBlock` instead of `Block` in your `Blocks` entity set and `Root.Children` property?

Or, if you know that `Block(5)` happens to be a `ParentBlock`, you can cast it before accessing its `Children` property. For example:

```
 odata/Block(5)/YourNamespace.ParentBlock/Children
```

Comment: Words cannot express how excited I am that it worked! I tried casting it but it didn't seem to work (though maybe I'll find out I was mistyped the namespace or something). For the first I essentially moved the list of children into the base Block class and everything that inherits from Block has to toggle a flag value that indicates whether it can have children or not. Thank you very much!